# iPhone 'Whole Word' Search

Tags: iphone, search

I am currently using the following algorithm to search on my iPhone app:

```
NSRange range = [entry.englishEntry rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(range.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [self.filteredListContent addObject:entry];
        }
```

The problem is that when I search for a word like 'crap' I also get results for words like 'scrap' which is irrelevant.  I am unfamiliar with NSRange so what is the search algorithm for searching the whole word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can search within words. You need to split the string into components first.  Then loop through each one and compare them.

Something like that:

```
  NSArray *words = [entry.english componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
  for (NSString *word in words)
  { 
      NSComparisonResult result = [word compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
      if (result == NSOrderedSame)
      {
        [self.filteredListContent addObject:entry];
        break;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the original problem. 'Scrap as part of a sentence' and 'Scrap' both contain 'crap'.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this problem by adding a simple category on NSString to do a word boundary search.  Here's the code:

```
@interface NSString (FullWordSearch)

// Search for a complete word. Does not match substrings of words. Requires fullWord be present
// and no surrounding alphanumeric characters.
- (BOOL)containsFullWord:(NSString *)fullWord;

@end

@implementation NSString (FullWordSearch)

- (BOOL)containsFullWord:(NSString *)fullWord {
    NSRange result = [self rangeOfString:fullWord];
    if (result.length > 0) {
        if (result.location > 0 && [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[self characterAtIndex:result.location - 1]]) {
            // Preceding character is alphanumeric
            return NO;
        }
        if (result.location + result.length < [self length] && [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[self characterAtIndex:result.location + result.length]]) {
            // Trailing character is alphanumeric
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: Note, this is not case insensitive. For that, use rangeOfString:options:

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the range of a string, just do a case-insensitive compare and check if the result is NSOrderedSame

```
if([entry.english caseInsensitiveCompare:searchText] == NSOrderedSame){
  [self.filteredListContent addObject:entry];
}
```

This will compare the text with the whole word and not just look for the range.

Comment: Thank You! However now it only picks up strings that begin with the searched word.  (i.e. 'Hello World!" is not picked up by typing in 'World')  I basically want to search strings for whole words anywhere in an Array of strings.

Comment: In my knowledge, there is no method is the NSString class which would let you do that! Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Now i make it as more generic, by using this code you can search any string between target string

```
    NSString * strName =[entry.english lowercaseString];

    if ([strName rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound) {
         [self.filteredListContent addObject:entry];}
```