# Find if string contains word

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa-touch

Note: String contains word, not string. I do know about `rangeOfString` method.

Example: "Designed by Apple in California" is not contains "App" word, but contains "Apple".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135524/iphone-whole-word-search has somewhat different requirement, and the accepted answer is not actually doing what the user wanted. In this case, case sensitivity is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word boundary `\\b` in your regex patterns to match whole words.

Here is an [example code](http://goo.gl/xC0Esy):

```
NSString *myText = @"Designed by Apple in California";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\bApple\\b" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSRange textRange = NSMakeRange(0, myText.length);
NSRange matchRange = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:myText options:0 range:textRange];
if (matchRange.location != NSNotFound)
    NSLog(@"There is a match!");
else
    NSLog(@"No match!");
```

With `@"\\bApple\\b"`, you will get a "There is a match!" message. With `@"\\bApp\\b"`, you will get "No match!".

Comment: Great answer! Note: it will match `Apple` in sentences like `(Apple-` which is great in my case.